# compiling with gcc broken for users but fine for root

Tags: debian, permissions, compiling, gcc

So somewhere along the way compiling as a regular user has stopped working on my server. I'm on Debian Stable. Can't think what has changed on my system that would result in this, or how to fix it, but now only root can compile.

```
user@box:~/code/helloworld$ gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
                 from helloworld.c:3:
/usr/include/features.h:356:25: fatal error: /usr/local/include/sys/cdefs.h: Permission denied
compilation terminated.
```

Compiling as root is fine. I presume this is a permissions issue?

```
As user@server:

ls -la /usr/local/include/sys/cdefs.h
ls: cannot access /usr/local/include/sys/cdefs.h: Permission denied

ls -la /usr/local/include/sys/       
ls: cannot access /usr/local/include/sys/.: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /usr/local/include/sys/..: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /usr/local/include/sys/apparmor.h: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /usr/local/include/sys/cdefs.h: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? apparmor.h
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? cdefs.h
```

The user can read /usr/local/include fine.
Root shows the perms on /usr/local/include/sys to be (note user is in staff group):

drwxr-Sr--  2 root staff  4096 Dec  7 08:20 sys

Location of cdefs.h

```
locate cdefs.h
/usr/include/ldap_cdefs.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
/usr/local/include/sys/cdefs.h
```

I've tried fixing the perms but I can't get it right. Is there a way to ignore the cdefs.h from /usr/local and use the one it /usr/include/?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a particularly good way to totally ignore it (it's possible with the gcc `nostdinc` switch, but then you will need to add -I for all necessary paths).

However, there is an easy way to force the compiler to choose the one you want.  According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html, the normal order of include paths is:

```
 /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```

Presumably this is to allow you to easily override a system include with a local user one.  But what trumps all those is -I, so if you compile:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/sys
```

Then it will pick *cdefs.h* from there.  It won't eliminate /usr/local/include from the path tho, so if there are other files that fall into this category you may need more -I's.  They are not recursive, so eg:

```
gcc -I/usr/include
```

Will not prioritize /usr/include/sys, just as the other version will not prioritize /usr/include.  So you might need:

```
gcc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sys
```

Using a makefile makes these kinds of things significantly easier, btw.  Eventually you will want to learn how to do that.

There may be some other problems you will run into related to whatever the reason for having this header duplicated is, but you'll have to explain that.  Is this your system?

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried fixing the perms but I can't get it right. Is there a way to ignore the cdefs.h from /usr/local and use the one it /usr/include/?

Yes, don't install them in `/usr/local/`. Debian will never install anything in `/usr/local`, so if there is files here, it's because you, other local administrators or badly packaged software installed these things here. Install them anywhere else. But installing another libc's headers in /usr/local is asking for trouble.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting stuff in `/usr/local`.  The reason Debian (or any other distro) does not install stuff there is because *that's not what it is for* -- it's for 3rd party software.  It is a **better** practice to use `/usr/local` for 3rd party stuff than to use `/usr` to avoid overwriting distro package stuff.  Of course, this can lead to duplications, but that is better than having replaced a system file with one from a 3rd party.

Comment: @goldilocks: The problem with having different software is `/usr` and `/usr/local` is not about duplication, it's about conflicts. Installing a libc in `/usr/local` IS Wrong. Put that (and everything third party) in `/opt`.

Comment: I'll agree that installing a libc in /usr/local should not be done willy-nilly.  Installing a libc in any standard path -- you do realize /usr/local is in that?  So what is it for? ;) -- on top of the distro one should not be done willy-nilly.  However, to say that "it is wrong to install software in /usr/local" is, well, just wrong.

Comment: @goldilocks: By installing software to `/usr/local`, you must abide to the fact that the software must be compatible with the existing software on your system/distribution, and any later update you may install. If you cannot guarantee that (and most of the time, you don't, or you don't care), then installing in `/usr/local` is wrong. `/usr/local` may be standard but so is `/opt`. Installing any software (including libcs) in `/opt` can be done willy-nilly and can be managed more easily.

Comment: @goldilocks, @BatchyX: well, installing anything you won't guarantee will work with updates **anywhere** is asking for troubles. The difference between `/usr` and `/usr/local` is historic: `/usr` often used to be a network mounted filesystem (usually read-only), and `/usr/local` was the place to put system-wide files that were present on local storage. `/opt` was intended for sw from other vendors.  Hence one of the main differences between `/usr/local` and `/opt` is, that the first is usually in `$PATH` and `/opt` should have per-application subtrees (today e.g. `/opt/kde3`).